# How to kill all my activities in android?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest

I am developing an Android application with few views like A,B,C,D.  Here D is my home activity. My navigation is like A->B->C->D. Once I reach Activity D, when I try to press back button, all previous activities (A,B,C) should close. I can't start activity like finish called calling new activity. Please provide me a way to kill activity of my application.

Here I've used some code to finish all activities but did not get result.

```
ActivityManager manager =  (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<RunningAppProcessInfo> list = manager.getRunningAppProcesses();

if(list != null)
{
    for(int i=0;i<list.size();++i) {
        if(getApplicationContext().getPackageName().matches(list.get(i).processName)) {
            int pid = android.os.Process.getUidForName(getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
            android.os.Process.killProcess(pid);
        } 
        else {
            debug.log("app not killed");
        }
    }
}
```

So please suggest me proper way to close all my activity at a time.

Thanks in advace

Comment: Do you want the user to be able to navigate backwards if he or she is in activity B or C?

Comment: Yes. i am able to give navigation between B & C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all who respond for my question. Finally i got the solution for my issue. I resolved that by using the intent Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP. Here is explanation for my scenario.
Assume i am in Activity D. My actual flow is A->B->C->D.i want to kill my previous activities A,B,C. I used to call my first activity A when i am going from Activity D. 
So i added intent FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP to call activity A. So the middle activities will cleared and will show only Activity A. And i am passing some flag value as intent extras to activity A. like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(D.this,A.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                intent.putExtra("finishstatus", true);
                this.startActivity(intent);
                this.finish();
```

and i am checking the bundle value in onCreate method of Activity A like

```
bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
        if(bundle!= null)
        {
            boolean isActivityToBeFinish = this.getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("finishstatus");
            if(isActivityToBeFinish)
            {
                finish();
                }
    }
```

If the status value available and it is true then i am finishing the activity A also. So my problem is cleared and i am successfully finishing the all previous activities.

May be my explanation is not good but will work perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

For finish it:

```
   Activity_name.this.finish();
```

And For killing :

```
  android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in two ways:

1. When you start your B activity from Activity A you can set a flag to the intent this way

   ```
   Intent i = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
   i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
   startActivity(i);
   ```

and do the same from B to C and from C to D

**OR**

2. After starting the activity call `finish()`

this will start the activity B and finishes the activity A, so when you click back you won't return to A activity.

```
    Intent i= new Intent(A.this, B.class);
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

In `onPause()` of the Activity_D set a flag like `public static boolean kill = true;`.

Now in Activities A, B, C's `onResume()` check if kill, then call `finish();`

```
onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(Activity_D.kill) {
        finish();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My workaround to the same problem:

Declare a singleton with an Activity Stack, and a public static clearAll method, that iterates the stack, finishing all the activities.

Then, I declare a StackedActivity extending Activity, which will be used in all my activities of the app.

In StackedActivity onCreate method, I add the instance to the stack singleton, and when I want to finish all, just call to the clearAll method.

Answer (score 0):

For Completely finish application

I concider that you are on launcher-Activity or your MainActivity From Where you doesn't wants to Resume your Application

1.Finish your Activity 
2.android:excludeFromRecents="true" in manifest

Comment: i have question asked. you may answer the same.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29735209/android-repeating-alam-is-not-getting-stopperd-on-the-stop-button-clicked

Answer (score 0):

Use
`finishActivity()`
after starting your activity