# android repeating alam is not getting stopped when stop button is clicked

Tags: java, android

I am setting a repeated alarm in the Android, which fires the activity.

This activity is having two buttons: "stop" and "snooze". When I click on "snooze" alarm is postponed to 10 minutes.

But the alarm is in slider window, i.e it is in onresume state.
I want to stop the alarm completely on both the buttons.

```
    public class RingAlarm extends Activity {

    MediaPlayer mp;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ring_alarm);
        Intent in;
        in = getIntent();

        String s=in.getStringExtra("habbit_id");
        int col= in.getIntExtra("habbit_Color",0);
        ScrollView sv = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.sv_ra);
        if(col<0)
        {
            sv.setBackgroundResource(R.color.red);
        }
        if(col>0) {
            sv.setBackgroundResource(R.color.green);
        }
        if(col==0)
        {
            sv.setBackgroundResource(R.color.yellow);
        }
        System.out.println("alarm string" + s);
        TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.habbit_ra);
        tv.setText(s);
       //  mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.song1);
        //mp.start();

    }
    public void onthecancelringclicked(View view){
        //mp.stop();
        int id=Process.myPid();
        finish();
        Process.killProcess(id);
        //System.exit(0);

    }

    public void onthesnoozeringclicked(View view){
        //mp.stop();
        long l=System.currentTimeMillis();
        Intent i = this.getIntent();
        Random r = new Random();
        int ri =r.nextInt(1000000)+64;
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,ri,i,0 );
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,l+600000,pi);

        finish();
        Process.killProcess(Process.myPid());
    }
}
```

And my XML file is:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@color/background"
>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:text="@string/app_name"
    android:gravity="left|center"
    android:padding="7dp"
    android:background="@color/user_profile"/>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/sv_ra">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/habbit_ra"
            android:text="habbit_name"/>

        <AnalogClock
            android:text="time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="bsy your self"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/habbit_message_ra"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:background="@color/user_profile">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="stop"
            android:background="@color/user_profile"
            android:onClick="onthecancelringclicked"/>
        <Button
            android:background="@color/user_profile"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="snooze 10 min"
            android:onClick="onthesnoozeringclicked"/>

        </LinearLayout>
```

As you can see I have implemented `Process.killProcess(pid)` method. Still my alarm is getting saved into the navigation drawer. I want to remove the activity from everywhere.

i am using same intent for 32 alarms so i can not put the id of the pending intent to the intent as putExtra.

Comment: Any reason you can't use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#cancel(android.app.PendingIntent) ?

Comment: because first i am not sure whether it will cancel the alarm or kill the activity and secondly i can not put the id of pending intent in the intent.putExtra because i am using same intent for 32 alarms.

Comment: Then use different intent for other alarms. I think cancelling alarm is really straight forward and you don't have to invent some complicated way to do it.

Comment: it is not a good way to implement a thing. when you only need a single intent, why you will create multiple objects leading to waste of memory. instead there should be a way to get the id of pending intent from the alarm activity

Comment: sir am.cancel will just cancel that alarm from the AlarmManager. it will not kill the activity that is fired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add the following lines in the entry of the activity that is fired in the menifest file.

```
android:excludeFromRecents="true"
```

this will not let the activity go into recents and calling finish will lead to end of the activity.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will give you an idea of how to cancel/stop the alarm:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyClass.class);
PendingIntent recurring = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
AlarmManager alarms = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    if(active) { //If alarm is active
        alarms.cancel(recurring);
        recurring.cancel();
    } else {
        // Do something..
    }
```

I copied it from one of my projects and it works for me.

Comment: i don't know the id of the pending intent in the alarm activity

Comment: You create one and use the same one when cancelling the alarm. In the code above it's `0` so you can change that to the one you're using in your activity.